# Microsoft Edge WebDriver unable to complete download or Rename it after download?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, download, selenium-edgedriver

I am writing an Selenium script which will download the file after clicking on the button.
And I put the time to 4min to complete but Manually it took less than 1 min to download.
And even After completed the script, downloaded file name contain .crdownload.
I compare the both file and it seems that file is downloading completely but there is always a chance that it did not downloaded properly since it contain .crdownload.

is there a way to in selenium or Edge WebDriver that will automatically rename it after this completed.

```
If EC.Presence_located_by_Element((By.ID,”btnExportExcel”)):
  Print(“ html elemnt found”)
  Driver.find_element(By.ID,”btnExportExcel”).click()
  time.sleep(480)
```

print(“ download is completed ”)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: before you quit the driver you need to poll/check the download directory for any files with .crdownload extension.  (don't rename... the browser will do that bit...)

Comment: Hi @browsermator, how should I do that poll/check. and I don't want to rename it but even after waiting of 5 min , it won't change back .csv. I updated my code which are initialing the download.

Comment: you just do that in your native code.  If you search here you'll find examples of it.  If the file never changes from .crdownload, then you can't do much.  The download has failed.

Comment: I  have the same inference but When I compare the .crdownload file with the correct downloaded file, it seems that it is both are same , And containing all the details, is it possible that Edge have some kind of bug that don't rename it after download compete.